# PBI how to map a date field to another dynamic table

Tags: powerbi

I have a main table with tasks and the date completed.  I wanted to put the completion dates into quarter buckets.  instead of building complicated if statements, I am thinking of having a separate dynamic table.  Is it possible to map the date completed in table1 into the respective buckets when it falls within the start and end dates of the quarters? if yes, how

[image]

Comment: managed to find this post which solves my case.
https://community.powerbi.com/t5/DAX-Commands-and-Tips/Lookup-value-if-date-is-between-two-dates/m-p/742143

Comment: A calendar table can be used for this issue, with dates and quarters etc in it